# Trace setState calls in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am having an issue in my app with constant rebuilds. I guess there is some side effect that triggers setState.

Is there a way to trace all setState calls in the whole app?

Answer (score 0):

flutter has amazing tools to handle all kind of stuff and specific what you want. Take a look at: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/overview